# How to use FontAwesome in a Dynamics 365 Portal?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, font-awesome-4, adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals

We have a website, which has been built up from the default Dynamics 365 portal; the header menu (primary navigation) has an item for 'home', when edited has a URL as **.fa.fa-home** an image derived from FontAwesome

We want to add another menu item, that also uses this style of image, but using other values, such as **.fa.fa-cloud-download** doesn't display anything. Have tried a few different names from the [W3Schools - FA4 list](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_intro.asp)
and none seem to work.

[image]

If the default for the Dynamics portals, is to use 'images', any idea where these images are hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Font Awesome, however the Portal uses a lot of out-of-date resources, so depending on the version that your icon was introduced, it may not be possible.

Try using an older icon (e.g. `fa fa-save`)

You can also see your options here `/css/glyphicons-font-awesome-migrate.min.css`

---

I just checked my portal and the `fa-cloud-download` icon is working, so make sure you're applying the icon correctly.

```
 <li role="none" class="weblink ">
   <a role="menuitem" aria-label="Home" href="/dashboard/" title="Home">
     <span class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   </a>
 </li>
```

Comment: The link to the CSS was spot on, thank you.